# How to omit children from element type in React with Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, typescript-generics

```
export type ComponentPropsWithoutChildren<
  Component extends ElementType,
  Props = {}
> = Props & Omit<ComponentPropsWithoutRef<Component>, keyof Props>;
```

How to omit `children` prop from element type?

If I have something like the following:

```
export const Input = ({
  className,
  children,
  href,
  ...props
}: ComponentPropsWithoutChildren<"input", InputProps>) => {
  return (
    ...
  );
};
```

`Placeholder` is okay, but `href` gets an error like:

---

> Property 'href' does not exist on type 'Omit<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>, "key" | keyof InputHTMLAttributes<...>>, never>'.ts(2339)

---

I'd like `children` to get a Typescript error as well

Comment: `export type ComponentPropsWithoutChildren<
  Component extends ElementType,
  Props = {}
> = Props & Omit<ComponentPropsWithoutRef<Component>, keyof Props | "children">;`
Does this do the job, not naively?